# Pegar maior valor existente em um array de números

Tags: javascript, array, matemática

Através deu uma função, eu retorno um array com inúmeros números aleatórios. Preciso pegar o maior número entre esse array, e para isso acabei achando a função `Math.max()`. O problema é que não consigo fazer ele ler meu array e em seguida me retornar o valor máximo... basicamente estou fazendo isso:

```
var retorno = [3,6,9,22,46,73];
var maiorNumero = Math.max(retorno); //retornaria 73
```

Alguém poderia me apresentar alguma solução para o fato?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

achei(rs), dentro de `Math.max()` eu tenho uma variação para trabalhar em cima de arrays programáticos que funciona da seguinte forma:

```
var retorno = [3,6,9,22,46,73];
var maiorNumero = Math.max.apply(Math,retorno); //ai sim retorna 73!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução simples seria:

```
int max = array.get(0);

for ( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if ( array.get(i) > max) {
      max = array.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: concordo, mas a de cima já é baseada em funções do DOM, portanto sua execução deve ser mais rápida, isso sem contar que a escrita é menor =D

Comment: Concordo que a apresentada por você é mais enxuta e isso é bom o algoritmo da minha resposta se aplica a quase qualquer linguagem mas recomendo o uso de funções nativas =D